# Can a ScrollView Work with a clickable TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a list of results from a search, and it needs to be scrollable, but I also need to be able to click on a result to go to another activity. Here is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:scrollbars="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/resultsLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="twoLine" android:id="@+id/tlli1">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MUDD PUPPIES SELF SERVE DOG " android:ellipsize="none"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="20091345" />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="oneLine" android:id="@+id/tlli2">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MUDD, ANGELA G " />
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="2008022979 3383 6" />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="oneLine" android:id="@+id/tlli3">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="GRABAU, ANDREW S " />
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="2011003340 3771 110 " />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="oneLine" android:id="@+id/tlli4">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="S M E T INC " />
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="1987016628 652 590 " />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="oneLine" android:id="@+id/tlli5">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A GOOD START INC " />
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="20040649" />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="oneLine" android:id="@+id/tlli6">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AGUILAR, JOHN D " />
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="2001015672 1747 306 " />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="oneLine" android:id="@+id/tlli7">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="THEIS, ARLENE C " />
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="1998020639 1439 544 " />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="oneLine" android:id="@+id/tlli8">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="R-E INVESTMENT CO " />
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="1985005167 530 925 " />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="oneLine" android:id="@+id/tlli9">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Man" />
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Machine" />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:mode="oneLine" android:id="@+id/tlli10">
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Man" />
            <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Machine" />
        </TwoLineListItem>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using a ListView for this sort of task, rather than rolling your own ScrollView.

**Edit:**

I think you're approaching this the wrong way. You're hardcoding the results of the search query in XML? That tells me that you aren't really doing a search query at all.

What you should be doing is having your data in an array or database and then query it appropriately and passing it to a `ListActivity` via an `ArrayAdapter` or `CursorAdapter`. Setting the `onListItemClicked()` function then will trivially allow you to send an intent with the appropriate data to your activity.

However, given that you look like you're quite a long way from this more optimal solution (though I highly commend you to explore it); you'll have to set lots of stuff manually.

In your Activity which uses the `ScrollView` layout, you'll need to define several `OnClickListener` and bind them to the appropriate element in the Scrollview. So something like:

```
TwoLineListItem tli1 = (TwoLineListItem) findViewById(R.id.tlli1);
tli1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourResultDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("foo", 1);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

And repeated for each of your ten items. `YourResultDetailActivity` should then get the Extras from the intent and use that to show the correct data.

Comment: my problem is that instead of being able to scroll and click, I can only scroll through results, and I can't click them

Comment: sorry, should have mentioned that I hardcoded this stuff in to show to a client but I will be perfoming search later on